# Spotfire Plugin Cache Settings, visualization not loading correctly in web interface. Any advice?

Tags: spotfire

I use a web interface to display spotfire visualizations using the spotfire plugin. I am currently having an issue where a small number of users are receiving an error when loading the visualizations in their browser.

I get "document property undefined errors" and in the navigation menu I've created one specific filter element displays grayed out with the message "Property control needs configuration"

I am currently using Spotfire 6.0, and have extensively searched http://support.spotfire.com/patches_spotfire.asp for possible solutions but have not successfully found any clear explanation of the problem.

If anyone has any experience with the spotfire plugin, PLEASE get back to me as soon as you can. Thanks so much!

Comment: What browser and versions was this happening on?

Comment: It is happening on Safari and Chrome, on all latest versions have not tested on older versions. Problem is only evident in a small number of users.

Comment: That's interesting. Does this happen to the users on different machines? If so, then i'd think it's a licenses issue. Specifically scripting.

Comment: Yes the users are on different machines, I am currently trying the solution that was detailed below. Will see how that works and will let you know. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Definitely let us know. Thanks for responding.

Comment: It works! The remember personalized view for each webplayer user was checked which seemed to be loading a cached version for some users. Definitely make note of this if you are ever using the webplayer!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem. Try going into the Document properties and uncheck the box that says "Remember personalized view for each webplayer user." That usually fixes it for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Will give it a try and let you know! Thanks!

Comment: IT WORKED! You are awesome, I have been stuck on this problem for 2 days!!! Thanks so much!

Comment: @RahatSyed be sure to upvote and/or accept this answer for future people

Comment: am trying! Don't seem to have enough comments to upvote, but this is the correct answer for everyone!!!!!

Comment: Thank you! this saved my day (using Spotfire 11)